# Python BeautifulSoup - Table return none when scraping by id

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape Daily Observation table from below given url https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/in/chennai/VOMM/date/2017-1-1

I want to use table id for scraping. I am using this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/in/chennai/VOMM/date/2017-1-1';
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'id' : 'history-observation-table'})
print(table)
```

But this is returning None. How can I scrape table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It dynamic page, you can use json data from URL like

```
https://api.weather.com/v1/geocode/12.99361134/80.17694092/observations/historical.json?apiKey=*********&startDate=20170101&endDate=20170101&units=e
```

you can see real API key it in browser Console -> Network

or use selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/in/chennai/VOMM/date/2017-1-1")

table = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda d: d.find_element_by_id('history-observation-table'))
print(table.text)
```